# ActiveRecord: Find records with non-blank/present fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL and Ruby On Rails

I would like to query the notes table but I don't want to return notes where the body column is NULL or consists solely of whitespace characters.

e.g.

```rb
Note.create!(body: "A note")
Note.create!(body: "")
Note.create!(body: nil)
Note.create!(body: "      ")
Note.create!(body: "  \n   \t\n ")

expect(Note.where(...).count).to eq(1) # the ... is what I was wondering about
```

What can I put in the `where` condition to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Using a regexp does the trick:

```rb
Note.where.not(body: nil).where.not("body ~* ?", '^\s*$')
```

Here we exclude the notes with a nil body or with an empty/blank body

If you wanted to have the note that have a blank body you would do:

```rb
Note.where(body: nil).or(Note.where("body ~* ?", '^\s*$'))
```

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried to address the issues in both the question and the answer

Comment: @engineersmnky I fixed the query to get blank bodies